# Doubt regarding finding the gradient of of a scalar field

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, vector-fields, slope

I am new to vector calculus.

I watched few you tube videos and came to the conclusion that `directional derivative` is something like slope with direction and its value is scalar while `gradient of a scalar` is the vector which has  magnitude and direction as that of directional derivative.Is my understanding correct.Please correct me if i am wrong.It would be great if you can point me some wonderful simple resource (any text book or video resource ) on which i can better understand the concept

Now i stumbled upon this exercise in one of my college text books

I am uploading the photo here

[image]

I hardly understand this question what does  $||\nabla f(x,y,z) || $  mean ..how come k becomes $\frac{5}{3}$ ..Which formula of is used here.Any help and suggestion will be highly appreciated .Thanks and regards in advance.

Now

Comment: pls tell me why was this question negative voted.Is this such a dumb question.Please help me understand the concept

Comment: The question is not dumb but badly formatted and lacks information about what you have tried. Please follow the instructions in [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @kurt G thanks a lot for pointing that out..I shall add further details and do formating

Comment: @Aplateofmomos thanks for trying to make me understand ..but i have few doubts what does " polli sanam question annu" --> can you convert this to english and can you please make more explanation on directional derivative ...""echera e pointene mari karinja ethara change ondam function ente value aguthe"" ---I didnt get this explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aplateofmomos for taking great pain and tremendous effort on trying to make me understand.Can you give me you link to chat with you.Thanks and lot with great respect

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120404/buraians-not-so-secret-hideout here it is. @MidhunRaj